# Scraping using rvest through multiple pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to figure out how to adapt the code below to scrape through the 100+ pages of search results. I've looked through other SO questions and it looks like 'purrr' might be the best library to use but I've struggled to make any of the suggestions work. The url of change.org seems to vary through "&offset=10", "&offset=20".

Any suggestions or other SO questions that I've missed would be much appreciated.

```
library(rvest)

#Specifying the url for website to be scraped
url <- 'https://www.change.org/search?q=PPE'

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrape HEADING & convert to text
title_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.xs-mbs') %>%  
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

#Using CSS selectors to scrape DATE & convert to text / nb. trim =true
date_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.symbol-clock+ span') %>%  
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
#Remove "Created" (not sure how to remove leading whitespace!!)
date_data <- gsub("Created","",date_data) 

#Using CSS selectors to scrape SUPPORTER NUMBERS & convert to text
supporters_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.symbol-supporters+ span') %>%  
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
#remove SPACE & 'supporters'
supporters_data<-gsub(" supporters","",supporters_data)

#Using CSS selectors to scrape PETITION TO/ADDRESSEE & convert to text
addressee_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.xs-mbn .type-s') %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
#remove "Petition to"
addressee_data<-gsub("Petition to ","",addressee_data)

#Using CSS selectors to scrape LOCATION & convert to text
location_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.plxxs') %>% 
  html_text(trim = TRUE) 

#Combining all the lists to form a data frame
change_df<-data.frame(Title = title_data, Addressee = addressee_data, Date = date_data,
                      Supporters = supporters_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a functional approach here - that is, building up a helper function that will allow you to scrape all the pages by just applying the same function to a vector of urls. Here's a little function that replicates your code:

```r
scrape_change_page <- function(url)
{
  webpage  <- xml2::read_html(url)
  
  get_text <- function(css) 
  {
    vec <- rvest::html_text(rvest::html_nodes(webpage, css), trim = TRUE)
    if(length(vec) < 10) c(vec, rep("", 10 - length(vec))) else vec
  }

  dplyr::tibble(
         title_data      = get_text('.xs-mbs'),
         date_data       = gsub("Created", "", get_text('.symbol-clock+ span')),
         supporters_data = gsub(" supporters", "", get_text('.symbol-supporters+ span')),
         addressee_data  = gsub("Petition to ", "", get_text('.xs-mbn .type-s')),
         location_data   = get_text('.plxxs')
         )
}
```

So if we test it on your url, we get a nice data frame (here it's actually shown as a tibble just for formatting purposes:

```
url <- 'https://www.change.org/search?q=PPE'

scrape_change_page(url)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    title_data      date_data  supporters_data addressee_data      location_data 
#>    <chr>           <chr>      <chr>           <chr>               <chr>         
#>  1 PPE FOR INDIAN~  22 Mar 2~ 31,521          Government of Indi~ India         
#>  2 Personal prote~  27 Mar 2~ 992,282         Matthew Hancock MP~ Liverpool, EN~
#>  3 Government mus~  3 May 20~ 208,747         UK Government       London, ENG, ~
#>  4 PPE for NHS st~  19 Mar 2~ 48,536          Matt Hancock        Woking, ENG, ~
#>  5 URGENT NEED fo~  28 Mar 2~ 36,773          Boris Johnson, Mat~ Hebburn, ENG,~
#>  6 PPE for all fr~  1 Apr 20~ 12,963          Public Health Engl~ Hartlepool, E~
#>  7 Appropriate PP~  29 Mar 2~ 4,996           Government          United Kingdom
#>  8 PPE for all Tf~  8 Apr 20~ 11,850          Transport For Lond~ Ilford, ENG, ~
#>  9 Mandate PPE fo~  22 Apr 2~ 11,068          Kay Ivey, Michael ~ Anoka, MN, US 
#> 10 Effective PPE ~  28 Mar 2~ 24,588          Ministry of Health  Christchurch,~
```

Now, if we want to get multiple pages into a single data frame, we generate a vector of urls that we want and `lapply` this function to get a list of data frames, which we then `rbind` into one large data frame. It seems there are 191 pages to scrape here, so I will just do 5 for the sake of the example:

```
n_pages <- 5
urls    <- paste0(url, "&offset=", 10 * (seq(n_pages) - 1)
result  <- do.call(rbind, lapply(urls, scrape_change_page))

result
#> # A tibble: 50 x 5
#>    title_data      date_data  supporters_data addressee_data      location_data 
#>    <chr>           <chr>      <chr>           <chr>               <chr>         
#>  1 PPE FOR INDIAN~  22 Mar 2~ 31,521          Government of Indi~ India         
#>  2 Government mus~  3 May 20~ 208,747         UK Government       London, ENG, ~
#>  3 Personal prote~  27 Mar 2~ 992,282         Matthew Hancock MP~ Liverpool, EN~
#>  4 PPE for NHS st~  19 Mar 2~ 48,536          Matt Hancock        Woking, ENG, ~
#>  5 PPE for all fr~  1 Apr 20~ 12,963          Public Health Engl~ Hartlepool, E~
#>  6 Appropriate PP~  29 Mar 2~ 4,996           Government          United Kingdom
#>  7 URGENT NEED fo~  28 Mar 2~ 36,773          Boris Johnson, Mat~ Hebburn, ENG,~
#>  8 PPE for all Tf~  8 Apr 20~ 11,850          Transport For Lond~ Ilford, ENG, ~
#>  9 Mandate PPE fo~  22 Apr 2~ 11,068          Kay Ivey, Michael ~ Anoka, MN, US 
#> 10 Effective PPE ~  28 Mar 2~ 24,588          Ministry of Health  Christchurch,~
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

And you can see `result` has 50 rows (10 from each page)

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you. Much clearer on the uses of `lapply` now too. Much appreciated